# hand balancing on canes

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, gymnastics, calisthenics

According to http://legendarystrength.com/hand-balancing-stands/ "[canes] actually make balancing easier while giving the appearance of more difficulty".

Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any of those exercises; however, based on the design of the canes, it seems very plausible that balancing will be easier. 
 
From observation, the base of the cane is much wider than the height *( or human palms)*; as a result, it provides a solid balancing base for the user. 
 
Equally important is the width of the cane's top; the design is flat and as wide as a human palm, which makes it easy to balance onto. 
 
The only two concerns are

- The metal frame must be strong enough to handle the user's weight.
- The user's height is further increased, which might be inconvenient for some people.

If these concerns are addressed, I don't see any reason why balancing shouldn't be easier with the cane.